# png files are not showing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, png

HI,
 All of a sudden today png files of my web application are not showing up in the browser.
 I am using Visual Studio 2008. The files are not even opening in the vs editor.
 When i double click on the icons in the vs editor it is saying 
 "Cannot load file. Unknown bitmap format." But so many days those were there and was working
 fine. So all of a sudden what happens them to not work?

Anybody has any suggestion?

Thanks & Regard,
Subrat.

Comment: Do your files open properly when you use a picture viewer (IE Windows Picture Viewer)?

Comment: yeah they open absolutely fine. But in visual studio editor they are not opening.

Comment: Even I am facing the similar kind of problem. Sometimes it shows images sometimes it doesn't. I tried this on IE V6, V7 and V8. Unable to diagnose the problem till now.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that they are not actually .PNG format under the hood, but were merely named that way.  Some browsers will work around this and some will not.  Try renaming them to .jpg, .bmp, .gif, etc., and for each test, change your `<img>` and see if it works in every browser.  When it does, you've found the right format.

An alternative is to open your file in a paint program and convert to PNG format (not merely PNG file extension) as you save.  Then you can be sure the format is correct.